# WordPress won't display errors at all

Tags: php, errors, debug, fatal-error

I have been having constant issue with WordPress not displaying errors at all and I have no clue what is wrong.

- PHP errors display on non-wordpress related pages.
- Debugging is turned on.
- Display errors in wordpress is turned on.
- PHP is allowed to display errors.
- This is a nginx webserver not apache.
- This happens with addons, plugins and themes. No errors at all just a white page.

Comment: When you say `Debugging is turned on`, do you mean `WP_DEBUG`? If you have [`WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY) set to `false`, errors will be hidden.

Comment: Both are set to true. Yet no errors are displayed.

Comment: you get a white screen? Try googling "How to Fix The White Screen of Death"

Comment: I have tried that many, many, many times. It was no help.